# How to remove a module from prestashop

Tags: prestashop

I am not able to remove the "new products", "specials", "our stories", "contact us" modules from the index page in Prestashop. Please, will any one tell me how to do it?

Thank you....

Comment: What have you tried so far? Backoffice->Modules uninstall didn't work? What was the error message you got?

Comment: i got no error message but the modules though i uninstalled are not getting removed.

Comment: It might be worth trying the additional steps outlined here - [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18717308/how-to-remove-a-module-from-prestashop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18717308/how-to-remove-a-module-from-prestashop)

Answer (score 1):

Check the database. In `ps_hook` table identify which `id_hook` these modules are attached to. Simply find e.g. row where name is `displayHome` and remember `id_hook`. Then look at `ps_module` table and identify modules ids which you are about to get rid of. At last check `ps_hook_module` table and find if there are rows where your `id_module` and `id_hook` match. If so just delete these rows.

If you don't find such matches, simply delete (and make an backup) of the modules from Prestashop installation folder/modules.

If this won't work these modules are only cached or you wrongly identified the modules you have uninstalled.

The case where uninstalled modules are not unhooked from Prestashop DB `ps_hook_module` table is important bug. Check if there isn't an override of `Module->uninstall()` function, which could cause such an situation.